# How to fix dis alignment of a ''input-group'' div element when resizing the window

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm setting up some input tags using bootstrap grid system. In a row, I'm having four input tags including a submit button. In the actual window, the elements are showing up as desired but when the screen is resized, some elements are moved down.

This code is running on angular 6

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>Package</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <select>
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected> --Please choose a 
          package--</option>
        <option> Fetching some data from backend </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>Start Date:</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>End Date:</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="OnSubmit()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm expecting is to get the row elements in the same line as to when it is resized also. but when the screen is resized, the row elements are dis aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a class missing:
class="form-control"

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>Package</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected> --Please choose a 
          package--</option>
        <option> Fetching some data from backend </option>
      </select>
    </div>

  <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>Start Date:</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <span>End Date:</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="OnSubmit()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```